# The multiplication of list of matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I need to multiply 3 lists of matrices (b.a.b) as the following code

```
a = {{{-17.8227277373099`, -1.6565234964560602`}, 
{-1.6565234954649242`, 
 5.298073701591974`}}, {{-17.812203521929003`, 
-1.5013126607114478`}, {-1.5013126574896714`, 
 4.384050851253119`}}, {{-17.801677045750512`, 
 -1.4055541329078751`}, {-1.405554138172727`, 
 3.869511752542245`}}};

b = {{{0.8409518416651456`, 0}, {0, 
 0.1274293000222242`}}, {{0.8409815693580924`, 0}, {0, 
 0.14187218616724442`}}, {{0.841011296000238`, 0}, {0, 
 0.15290209433231844`}}};
```

I used the following:

```
  mat = b.a.b
```

But, I think this way is not correct because I didn't get the result. Also, I make a test for the first matrices as the following code, that what I wanted to get for the whole matrices multiplication.

```
 a1 = {{-17.8227277373099`, -1.6565234964560602`}, 
{-1.6565234954649242`, 5.298073701591974`}};

b1 = {{0.8409518416651456`, 0}, {0, 0.1274293000222242`}};

 mat1 = b1.a1.b1


 {{-12.6042, -0.177516}, {-0.177516, 0.0860313}}

Thanks.
```

Comment: `Table[b[[i]].a[[i]].b[[i]], {i, 1, 3}]` or `#[[2]].#[[1]].#[[2]] & /@ Transpose[{a, b}]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot corey979!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `MapThread` and `Dot`:

```
MapThread[Dot, {b, a, b}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It is the easiest!

Answer (score 6):

If you need it really fast, then use `Compile`:

```
n = 1000000;
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2, 2}];
b = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2, 2}];

cf = Compile[{{a, _Real, 2}, {b, _Real, 2}},
   b.a.b,
   RuntimeAttributes -> Listable,
   Parallelization -> True
   ];

MapThread[Dot, {b, a, b}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
cf[a, b]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 1.46343
>
> 0.075722

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome.